# Небольшой вопрос по ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Здравствуйте, не могу понять почему при добавлении в ArrayList элемента в классе main все проходит по плану, а при использовании этих строк в другом классе например как ниже, не происходит ничего.

```
public class Company {

ArrayList<String> unitList = new ArrayList<String>();
unitList.add(0,"Абырвалг");
}
```

Подписывает синтаксическую ошибку и все.

И второй вопрос каким то образом можно создать ArrayList например в котором будут указываться все наследники вышеуказанного класса к примеру ?
Задание дословно звучит так "создать класс компания и создать в нем список подразделений компании." 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Company {

private List<String> unitList;

public Company(){
    unitList = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void add(String unit){
unitList.add(unit);
}

public List<String> unitList(){
  return unitList;
}
}
```

сделайте класс подобно этому. Тут компания держит юниты.
как использовать

```
Company company = new Company();
company.add("Buxgalteriya");
company.add("IT");
```

Answer (score 2):

Код не может быть прямо в классе. Положите его, например, в метод. Иначе непонятно, в какой же момент его выполнять?

Исходя из вашего задания, возможно, вам следует поместить инициализацию в *конструктор*.

---

По второму вопросу, вам нужен для начала тип данных для подразделения компании. Если он есть (допустим, это `Subsidiary`), то просто заведите `List<Subsidiary>`.